# Replace Parameter Query Based on User Selection

Tags: excel

I am currently pulling data from a sql database using a parameter query. I have a drop down list were it replaces the parameter with what the user selects.

example drop down: GP, FP, Both.

If user selects GP then the ? in the query is replaced by either GP. If user selects FP then ? is replaced by FP. How can I replace my query if the user selects BOTH so that GP, and FP are both in the parameter query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where IN('GP', 'FB')`. or you can remove filter to get all data.

Comment: i understand that but how can i choose "BOTH" in my drop down and replace the query with in('GP', 'FP')